# When doing a cast conversion in Flex 4, can you cast convert "anything" to "anything?"

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, casting

I'm building a custom component and I need to convert the event that is passed to the method into a mouse event. I can do this but it is telling me that I'm getting a null reference of an object. Here is how I am calling it.

```
public function dragStart(e:MDIWindowEvent): void {
    var mouse:MouseEvent = (e.currentTarget as MouseEvent);
    trace(mouse.localX);//<-----Null Error
}
```

How can I go by converting the MDIWindowEvent to a MouseEvent? If I can at that.

Comment: does your `MDIWindowEvent` extend `MouseEvent` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are casting the Event target not the event it won't work.
Also you can't cast an MDIWindowEvent as a MouseEvent.

What you can try is:

```
public function dragStart(e:MDIWindowEvent): void {
    trace(e.currentTarget.mouseX);
}
```

Rob

Comment: Shouldn't he be able to cast a MDIWindowEvent as a MouseEvent if that event class extends MouseEvent?  Oherwise, +1

Comment: @www.Flextras.com: Only if it extends MouseEvent, otherwise it will always evaluate to null. It's one of the ways of checking of type of the parameter, ie. you can do `if (var1 is SomeClass)`, `if (var1 as SomeClass)` or `if (SomeClass(var1))`.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com only if it does but it doesn't by default. http://flexlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/flexlib/mdi/events/MDIWindowEvent.html

Comment: @Maurycy, `if (SomeClass(var1))` will cause an exception if `var1` can't be cast [in as3](http://www.darronschall.com/weblog/2006/02/actionscript-3-casting.cfm).

Comment: @jswolf19, indeed, my bad. I was pretty sure it did work, that I even used it before, but my memory must be fuzzy.

Comment: @Maurycy, according to the link, it did in as2 (before `as` was introduced), if you've used that.

Answer (score 1):

if MDIWindowEvent doesn't extend MouseEvent, this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The `as` returns the object casted or `null` if the object cannot be casted. It cannot be casted if it's not a subclass of what you're trying to cast to. This way you can recover if the cast does not work as planned.